# Using flatten logic in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the below query, I need to join another table called table_2 based on common column which is TID column. I need to add some conditions in the WHERE clause and for that I need to join table_2.

How to achieve this?

```
  SELECT id,LISTAGG(DISTINCT apn_no,';')WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY apn_no) as apn_no
   from
   (SELECT id,
      CASE WHEN INDEX = 1 AND item_list!='' THEN item_list END AS apn_no
     FROM (
        SELECT id,index,d.value::string AS item_list FROM (
                        SELECT id,c.value::string AS item_list
                          FROM table_1,LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(p_list, ',')) c 
                      ), LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(item_list, ';')) d
       )where item_list is not null
     )
   GROUP BY id
```

Comment: You’d need to provide the DDL for the table you want to join to, which columns you want to join on, etc. before anyone can help you. It’s a bit surprising that you can write a query using lateral flatten but don’t know how to join tables - so am I missing something from your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [Snowflake SQL grammar](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs.html), cut'n'pasted straight from the doc's. It's might be time to do some learning/reading.

The JOIN goes after the FROM

```
[ WITH ... ]
SELECT
   [ TOP <n> ]
   ...
[ FROM ...
   [ AT | BEFORE ... ]
   [ CHANGES ... ]
   [ CONNECT BY ... ]
   [ JOIN ... ]
   [ MATCH_RECOGNIZE ... ]
   [ PIVOT | UNPIVOT ... ]
   [ VALUES ... ]
   [ SAMPLE ... ] ]
[ WHERE ... ]
[ GROUP BY ...
   [ HAVING ... ] ]
[ QUALIFY ... ]
[ ORDER BY ... ]
[ LIMIT ... ]
```